# A question about differential function

Tags: calculus

If $f(x)=f'(x^{2})+2x$, then $f(1)=?$ and $f''(1)=?$

Sorry. I am going to check the original problem, and then i will update.

Comment: Is this a differential equation?  So $f(x)=2x(f'(x^2) +1)$?

Comment: I'm so sorry. I wrote the equation wrong. Let me edit it.
Now I wrote it right.

Comment: Are you sure you gave the complete problem? Your equation is a first-order differential equation, even if a somewhat-strange one. There usually is an infinite number of solutions, with one degree of freedom. To get definite answers to your questions we would need one more fact, such as $f(0)$ or perhaps $f'(1)$. As written, your question is unanswerable.

Comment: I understand. I am going to check the original problem, and then i will update.

Comment: This doesn't need to be unsolvable. By evaluating this equation at zero and then evaluating its derivatives at zero we can get value of the function and all of its derivatives at zero. If we assume it is analytic in some big enough region this allows to get the value at 1.

Comment: $f(1)=f'(1)+2$ and $f''(1)=f'(1)/2-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the equation $f(x) = f'(x^2) + 2x$. It can be seen that $f(1) = 4$, $f'(1) = 2$ and $f^{(n+2)}(1) = 0$ for $n \geq 0$. The demonstration of how these values are obtained is as follows.

---

Since $f(x)$ is differentiable, which is evident from the differential equation, then consider the function in a series expansion given by
\begin{align}
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} \, x^{n}
\end{align}
for which the equation given leads to
\begin{align}
a_{0} + a_{1} \, x + a_{2} \, x^2 + a_{3} \, x^3 + \cdots &= 2x + (a_{1} + 2 \, a_{2} \, x^2 + 3 \, a_{3} \, x^4 + 4 \, a_{4} \, x^6 + \cdots ) \\
&= a_{1} + 2 x + 2 \, a_{2} \, x^2 + 3 \, a_{3} \, x^4 + 4 \, a_{4} \, x^6 + \cdots .
\end{align}
Equating coefficients provides $a_{0} = a_{1}$, $a_{1} = 2$, $a_{n+ 2} = 0$ for $n \geq 0$. Hence 
\begin{align}
f(x) = 2 (x+1).
\end{align}
Now it is easy to obtain $f'(x) = 2$ and $f^{(n+2)}(x) = 0$ for $n \geq 0$. Letting $x=1$ provides the desired results.